# Better way to use DI in Data Access layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I have created a simple 3 tier architecture using Unity to achieve DI. But still I want to know how can I more improve the code specifically the Data Access layer. My application is simply getting some input from the user and then fetching the data from DB in Data Access Layer.

```
  public class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Bootstrapper.Init();
        Initiator initiator = DependencyInjector.Retrieve<Initiator>();

        Console.Write("Enter Department Id: ");
        int departmentId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int count = initiator.FetchData();
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
 }

 public static class Bootstrapper
 {
    public static void Init()
    {
       DependencyInjector.Register<IBusiness, BusinessClass>();
       DependencyInjector.AddExtension<DependencyOfDependencyExtension>();
    }
 }

public class DependencyOfDependencyExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IData, DataClass>();
    }
}

 public static class DependencyInjector
 {
    private static readonly UnityContainer UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    public static void Register<I, T>() where T : I
    {
        UnityContainer.RegisterType<I, T>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
    public static void InjectStub<I>(I instance)
    {
        UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(instance, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
    public static T Retrieve<T>()
    {
        return UnityContainer.Resolve<T>();
    }
    public static void AddExtension<T>() where T : UnityContainerExtension
    {
        UnityContainer.AddNewExtension<T>();
    }
 }
```

In data access layer I am calling the following method:

```
 public int GetCount(int departmentId)
    {
        int count = 0;
        switch (departmentId)
        {
            case 10001:
                // select query
                break;
            case 10002:
                // select query
                break;
            case 10003:
                // select query
                break;
            case 10004:
                // select query
                break;
            case 10005:
                // select query
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

All the cases have different queries and in those different queries I am fetching the count using Dept ID. My concern is every time there will new department added I have to add new queries as well new case in the Switch.

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: If this is already working code and you are looking for improvement suggestions then this question would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with DI. It looks to me like you need simply need to make a parameterized sql query.

Comment: @Crowcoder: I am not directly using SQL queries instead of Odata queries. That's, why can't use parameterized sql queries or Stored proc.

Comment: Since `GetCount` returns an `int` but, according to the comments, it executes queries, it looks like you're executing different queries depending on `departmentId`. If you included a sample in your code that would help. It looks like you have a whole lot of *something* in that method and you want to break it up, which is good. We just need to see what it is.

Comment: @ScottHannen: In that code, there will be different queries having different tables to fetch the count nothing more. Now that is the problem since for each dept id I have a different set of queries I have to check them, execute them and return the data using a Switch case. I was looking at a better approach to do that.

Comment: I'm still not completely clear on it, and I don't want to give you an overengineered solution. Is it just the SQL query that changes? Can you just select the SQL string in your `switch` and then execute it after the `switch`? That way the code to open a connection, execute the command, etc. isn't repeated.

Comment: Can you show at least two query examples? OData can be parameterized too so it is unclear why you need to code specifically for every departmentId.